# Was the "anti-suffragist Beresford Hope" related to Alexander Beresford Hope?

Tags: united-kingdom

From a bit of UK suffragette [history/fight](https://books.google.com/books?id=U4Y6Jyc0vSAC&pg=PA58):

> The election of Lady Sandhurst was instantly challenged by the anti-suffragist Beresford Hope, whom Lady Sandhurst had defeated. *Beresford Hope v. Sandhurst* reached court on 18 March 1889 and went to appeal in May of that year [...]

Is this "anti-suffragist Beresford Hope" related to [Alexander Beresford Hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Beresford_Hope)? It couldn't have been him because ABH died in 1887 so maybe a descendant or some relative... Does anyone know the details as whom the "anti-suffragist Beresford Hope" was?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The “anti-suffragist Beresford Hope” was actually *[Charles Thompson Beresford-Hope](https://london.wikia.org/wiki/Charles_Thompson_Beresford-Hope)*.

The article notes that:

> He was the youngest son of the Rt. Hon. Sir Alexander James Beresford Hope, a prominent Conservative Party member of parliament.

---

Wikipedia also has an article which lists the [members of London County Council 1889–1919](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_London_County_Council_1889%E2%80%931919).

Perhaps surprisingly, given the significance of the case of Berseford Hope v. Sandhurst in the history of women's suffrage in the UK, it appears that nobody has yet created a Wikipedia page for Charles Thompson Beresford-Hope himself.